# C program that reads a file the user inputs and returns the first line

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv)
  {
    FILE* file;
    char scratch[1024];
    char filename[1024] = argv[1];
    file = fopen( filename, "r" );
    if( file != NULL ){  
        if( fgets( scratch, 1024, file ) != NULL ){    
            fprintf( stdout, "read line: %s", scratch );  
        }  
        fclose(file);
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Essentially if the user was to run
./nameOfTheProgram nameOfTheTextFile
it should return the first line of the Text File

I'm getting the following error:
error: invalid initializer
char filename[1024] = argv[1];

Comment: This is not an answer, but why don't you use argv[1] directly?

Comment: You cannot initialize char arrays with non-literal strings.  If you want to save a reference to the argument, just use `const char* filename = argv[1];`.  If you need to copy it into the array, use `strncpy`.

Comment: I want the user to be able to input any file, not just hard coding the name of argv[1] into the problem making it always run the first like of that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     ... your variables
     char *filename;

     if (argc>1)
     {
         filename = argv[1];
     }
     else
     {
         fprintf(stderr, "need a filename\n");
         exit(1);
     }

     ... your code
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you!